# Module custom page 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, controllers, 404

An extension I'm using creates two custom pages in website:

`app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/scommerce_competition.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <competition_index_index>
        <label>Competition</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Competition</title></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/competition.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="scommerce_competition/entry" name="entry" template="scommerce/competition/entry.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </competition_index_index>

    <competition_index_enter>
        <label>Competition</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Competition</title></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scommerce/jquery-1.8.3.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/competition.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="scommerce_competition/success" name="success" template="scommerce/competition/success.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </competition_index_enter>
</layout>
```

`competition_index_index` works ok but `competition_index_enter` page gives 404 not found error.

`etc/config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <competition>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Scommerce_Competition</module>
                <frontName>competition</frontName>
            </args>
        </competition>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <competition>
                <file>scommerce_competition.xml</file>
            </competition>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

What could cause this error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`<competition_index_index>` means : `<routername_controllername_actionname>`

So for `<competition_index_index>` and `<competition_index_enter>`, you'll have :

> app/code/local/Scommerce/Competition/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Scommerce_Competition_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    /*<competition_index_index>*/

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /*<competition_index_enter>*/

    public function enterAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

Clean the **Magento** and **Browser** `cache` and it should work.